# Optimised Optional Search In DatagridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

For Example I have 4 `textbox` and 4 `comboBox` and i want to search in `DatagridView` with the values 
entered in that `textboxes` and `comboBoxes` and **i do not want to search with empty ones**.
I can do this work with if Condition but i think it is not Optimised and is very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Get the data from sql server in to static list when the page load.
then in filter button click event,
add 8 if statements like`if(combox1.checked){
list.Where(obj=>obj.<field name for that combobox>)` like wise filter step by step. Following is example code. i think you may understand that.

```
static List<CRMIssueHeader> issueheader=new List<CRMIssueHeader>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnUpdate.Visible = false;
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        { 
            issueheader = _CRMService.CRMTRN02_GetIssueHeader();
        }
    }

protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<CRMIssueHeader> IHeader = new List<CRMIssueHeader>();
        IHeader = issueheader;
       //_CRMService = new CRMService();
        //issueheader  = _CRMService.CRMTRN02_GetIssueHeader();
        if (!chknew.Checked)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.IssueStatus != 0).ToList();
        if (!chkWIP.Checked)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.IssueStatus != 1).ToList();
        if (!chkFixed.Checked)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.IssueStatus != 2).ToList();
        if (chkAccepted.Checked)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.IssueStatus != 3).ToList();
        if (chkClarification.Checked)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.IssueStatus != 4).ToList();
        if (chkCancel.Checked)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.IssueStatus != 5).ToList();
        if (chkOnHold.Checked)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.IssueStatus != 6).ToList();
        if (ddlCustomers.SelectedValue.ToString() != "All")
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.CustomerCode == ddlCustomers.SelectedValue.ToString()).ToList();
        if (txtFrom.Text.Length != 0 && txtTo.Text.Length != 0)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.ReportedOn >= DateTime.Parse(txtFrom.Text) && obj.ReportedOn <= DateTime.Parse(txtTo.Text)).ToList();
        else if (txtFrom.Text.Length != 0 && txtTo.Text.Length == 0)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.ReportedOn >= DateTime.Parse(txtFrom.Text)).ToList();
        else if (txtFrom.Text.Length == 0 && txtTo.Text.Length != 0)
            IHeader = IHeader.Where(obj => obj.ReportedOn <= DateTime.Parse(txtTo.Text)).ToList();
        else ;
```

}